# How to explain the rationality of a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This an exercise from an elementary number theory textbook:

"The curve

$$y^2 = x^3 + 8$$

contains the points $(1, -3)$ and $(-7/4, 13/8)$.  The line through these two points intersects the curve in exactly one other point.  Find that third point.  Can you explain why the coordinates of this third point are rational numbers?"

The coordinates of the third point are $\left(\frac{433}{121},-\frac{9765}{1331}\right)$.  This post is about the question on why this point's coordinates are rational.

---

My solution: The general equation for a (non-vertical) line through $(-7/4, 13/8)$ is

$$y - \frac{13}{8} = m \left(x + \frac{7}{4}\right)$$

The solutions for the intersection between this line and the curve are

$$
\begin{array}{}
x = -\frac{7}{4}, & y = \frac{13}{8} \\
x = \frac{1}{8} \left(7 + 4 m^2-\sqrt{16 m^4+168 m^2+208 m-147}\right), & y = \frac{1}{8} \left(4 m^3 + 21 m + 13 - m \sqrt{16 m^4+168 m^2+208 m-147}\right) \\
x = \frac{1}{8} \left(7 + 4 m^2+\sqrt{16 m^4+168 m^2+208 m-147}\right), & y = \frac{1}{8} \left(4 m^3 + 21 m + 13 + m \sqrt{16 m^4+168 m^2+208 m-147}\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

Of the three solutions, two are given in terms of $m$.  We know that one of these solutions, namely $(1, -3)$, is rational.  This, and the fact that $m$ is rational, imply that the square root term that appears in all the other solutions, namely

$$\sqrt{16 m^4+168 m^2+208 m-147},$$

must also be rational.

---

Something doesn't seem right about this solution (too complicated, especially for an introductory textbook; too specific).  Is there a better way to answer the question?

Comment: $$(y-4)(y+4)=x^3-2^3$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: that's a nice maneuver, but I don't see how it gets at the desired answer.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @kjo Yup, that factorization seems to miss the point entirely: this is a very general phenomenon with interesting consequences (elliptic curve group law).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = ax + b$ be the equation for the line through the two points. Note that $a$ and $b$ are rational (their exact value doesn't matter in what follows, but their rationality does). Insert that for $y$ in the equation for the curve:
$$
(ax + b)^2 = x^3 + 8 \implies x^3 - a^2x^2 - 2abx + 8-b^2 = 0
$$
This third degree equation has three solutions. Two of them are given ($-7/4$ and $1$). The third one we can extract by Vieta's formulas: we know that the sum of all three roots is equal to $a^2$ (or that their product is equal to $b^2 - 8$, but you get the same result). Thus the third root is given by $x = a^2 +7/4 - 1$, which is clearly rational. Since the $x$-value is rational, and the $y$-value is given by $ax + b$, the $y$-value is rational as well.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the curve and the line gives a cubic in $x$ with rational coefficients. So the sum of its roots must be rational. You already know two of them are rational, so the third must be also. The corresponding $y$-coordinates are also rational because the equation of the line has rational coefficients.